# Java ModelMapper map an object in an object

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, modelmapper

I have the following DTO and VO:

VO

```
public class ProjectVO {
    private Date fechaInicio;
    private Date fechaFin;
}
```

DTO

```
public class ProjectDTO {
   private String fechaInicio;
   private String fechaFin;
}
```

And the following converter to convert the strings to dates:

```
Converter<String, Date> dateConverter = new Converter<String, Date>()
    {
        public Date convert(MappingContext<String, Date> context)
        {
            Date date;

            try {
                date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(context.getSource());
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                throw new DateFormatException();
            }

            return date;
        }
    };

modelMapper.addConverter(dateConverter);
```

If I convert a single String to a date using modelmapper it'll work perfectly with this converter.

But now I need to convert my ProjectDTO object to a ProjectVO one and I am getting an error saying that it cannot convert a String to a Date. I suspect this is because the Date is inside the Project object. Am I right? How can I solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: You have to define a `Converter<ProjectDTO, ProjectVO>`

Comment: Is that the only way to do it @roookeee ?

Comment: I see you are using modelmapper which supports automatic mappings, maybe your configuration is wrong? Read the [documentation](http://modelmapper.org/getting-started/#setting-up) for guidance

Comment: Yes, I know about that. But how would you initialize a Date from a string? Dates object don't have a set methor or anything similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay it works like a charm and automatically detects it if I use this:

```
modelMapper.createTypeMap(String.class, Date.class);
```

and then add the custom converter I created :)